# MeshCollider on a procedurally generated Spherical mesh is not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on procedurally generating celestial bodies. Plan is to cover as many as possible, but at the moment I have only got the configuration ready for stars, planets, moons and asteroids.

Anyway, back on the primary point. I want to be able to walk around on the randomly generated planets and for that, I need to assign a mesh collider to the Sphere mesh I am using for the terrain generation.

I made sure to add the MeshCollider component after I have assigned the mesh to the meshfilter, just in case. And after all the noise layers are done with the "sculpting" of the vertices of that mesh, I set the collider mesh to the meshfilter mesh.

```
    terrainMeshFilter.sharedMesh = shapeSettings.CreateTerrain(origin);
    if(terrainSphere.GetComponent<MeshCollider>() == null) terrainSphere.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    terrainSphere.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = null;
    terrainSphere.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().sharedMesh = terrainMeshFilter.sharedMesh;
```

I tested this, and it didn't produce the expected results. The player is, for some reason, floating. I have made sure to apply a "gravity" force, pulling the player towards the planet like so:

```
        Rigidbody rb = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Transform playerTransform = player.GetComponent<Transform>();
        Vector3 gravityDirection = (playerTransform.position - origin).normalized;

        if(rb != null){
            rb.useGravity = false;
            rb.isKinematic = true;
            rb.AddForce(gravityDirection * gravity);
        }
```

But the player is stuck "midair". It won't stick to the ground. And another weird thing that is happening is that, if I "run" around the planet with the player midair, and hit some mountain sticking up very highly, then the collision with the mountain is registered correctly. That would suggest that the MeshCollider is assigned correctly, but if that is the case, why is the player floating midair?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Note: I have also assigned some images below picturing the problem from the player's perspective on the planet, and from a third person perspective outside the planet (the capsule is the player).

[image: Player Perspective]

[image: Third-Person Perspective]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the mesh wireframe is impossible to give you a proper answer, but judging from the little code you have shared I'd say that your mesh doesn't coincide with your actual mesh data. This can easily be because you are using **sharedMesh** instead of **mesh**: especially on a procedurally generated object those data might not match at all, and writing them can cause undesired effects.

Also, about gravity, your approach is too simplistic. Have a look at [this video about faux gravity systems and attractors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHeQ8Hr92P4) for walking on planets.

~Pino

Comment: Okay, I saw that video and it's not so different from what I am already doing. I am handling the player rotation some other place, and I didn't include it here. But that bit works. As for the main problem. The MeshCollider component does not have a "mesh" variable. Only a sharedMesh. That's why I used that. If you wish to see the wireframe of the mesh, here it is: https://prnt.sc/upu1ys Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hi, the image is not very clear: can you take an orthographic wireframe shot with the player? Also, your variable gravityDirection is actually the Gravity Up direction because you are subtracting the player from the planet centre, not the other way around.

Comment: Yes, but the "gravity" is a negative value, so I am guessing it's the same thing as getting the proper direction? I use the gravity direction vector for calculating the rotation around the planet too, that's why I am getting the inverse direction if you were wondering why I am going about it this way. 
Image1: https://prnt.sc/upvomg 
Image2: https://prnt.sc/upvoyb

Also, do you think the CharacterController component is messing around with the rigidbody physics and preventing the gravity force from being applied? I have had problems with that in the past, but not of this nature.

Comment: Okay, yeah it was definitely the CharacterController. I disabled it and the player fell to the ground. I guess I am going to have to write my own player movement script. I am wondering what is going wrong with the CharacterController that is messing up the Force application though. Very annoying. Nevertheless, thank you for your time.

Comment: You are very welcome! So you are using the Unity Character Controller? That I'm afraid is well-known for not playing well with others, especially physics.